# FullCalendar Scheduler eventMouseover for Resources

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

My resource list is a list of users for my scheduler. I would like to show a tooltip when hovering over them that displays user specific information. I can do this easily for events with the eventMouseover but can someone help me do this for resources?

I have all of the user info I just do not know how to make the tooltip appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the resourceRender function http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_rendering/resourceRender/

```
function resourceRenderCallback(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds){
    var title = 'Name: ' + resourceObj.title;
    labelTds.attr('title', title);
}
```

From here you can add whatever you desire to title. Another possibility is

```
labelTds.on('hover', function(){console.log('hover');});
```

which would allow any jquery event to be triggered for the resource